# VBA Excel run time error 13 type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

I have an issue with the InputBox. my macro was working well. and this is my code 
so i find on google that if the CInt function is supplied with a text string that cannot be converted into a numeric value, it will return the error, is it true? or any advise?

```
Private Sub btn_check_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim a, b, x, y, z, c As Long
Dim indicator, puzzlePartner, puzzleRaw As String

a = 5
b = 2
c = 5

Do Until Cells(c, 1) = ""
     Sheet9.Cells(c, 3).Select
        Sheet9.Cells(c, 56) = Trim(CStr(Left(Sheet9.Cells(c, 3), 15)))
    c = c + 1
    Loop

a = 5

Do Until Sheet9.Cells(a, 1) = ""
    Do Until Sheet4.Cells(b, 104) = ""
        If a = 2000 Then
        c = 1
        End If
    If Sheet4.Cells(b, 9) = Sheet9.Cells(a, 9) And Sheet4.Cells(b, 27) = Sheet9.Cells(a, 27) And Sheet4.Cells(b, 26) = Sheet9.Cells(a, 26) And _
         Sheet4.Cells(b, 25) = Sheet9.Cells(a, 25) And Sheet4.Cells(b, 24) = Sheet9.Cells(a, 24) And Sheet9.Cells(a, 52) = Sheet4.Cells(b, 104) And _
         LCase(Trim(Sheet4.Cells(b, 21))) = LCase(Trim(Sheet9.Cells(a, 21))) Then
         Sheet9.Cells(a, 53) = "True"
        GoTo 1
    ElseIf CInt(Cells(2, 3)) <> Year(Sheet9.Cells(a, 9)) And Sheet9.Cells(a, 15) = "Withdrawn" Then
        Sheet9.Cells(a, 53) = "True"
        GoTo 1
    ElseIf CInt(Cells(2, 3)) <> Year(Sheet9.Cells(a, 9)) And Sheet9.Cells(a, 15) = "DC" Then
        Sheet9.Cells(a, 53) = "True"
        GoTo 1
    ElseIf CInt(Cells(2, 3)) <> Year(Sheet9.Cells(a, 9)) And Sheet9.Cells(a, 15) = "PO" Then
        Sheet9.Cells(a, 53) = "True"
        GoTo 1
    ElseIf Right(Sheet9.Cells(a, 7), 3) = "(S)" Then
        Sheet9.Cells(a, 53) = "True"
        GoTo 1
     ElseIf CInt(Cells(2, 3)) <> Year(Sheet9.Cells(a, 51)) And Sheet9.Cells(a, 15) = "APP" Then
        Sheet9.Cells(a, 53) = "True"
        GoTo 1
    ElseIf CInt(Cells(2, 3)) <> Year(Cells(a, 12)) And Right(Cells(a, 52), 3) = "RNW" Then
        Sheet9.Cells(a, 53) = "True"
        GoTo 1
        End If
    End If
2:
    b = b + 1
    Loop
            Sheet9.Cells(a, 53) = "False"
x = CInt(Len(Sheet9.Cells(a, 52)))
            y = x - 4
            indicator = Mid(Sheet9.Cells(a, 52), y, 1)
            If Sheet9.Cells(a, 53) = "False" And indicator = "-" Then
                Sheet9.Cells(a, 53) = "Top-up"
          End If
1:

    b = 2
a = a + 1
Loop
```

I have also noticed that this error is shown on the line

```
     ElseIf CInt(Cells(2, 3)) <> Year(Sheet9.Cells(a, 51)) And Sheet9.Cells(a, 15) = "APP" Then
```

Anyone have idea why is this happening?

Comment: This: `Dim a, b, x, y, z, c As Long` doesn't do what you think it does. `c` is defined as a long, but all the other ones are defined as `Variant` - That is not a shortcut to Dimming variables of the same type.And the same goes for `Dim indicator, puzzlePartner, puzzleRaw As String`

Comment: And do not use `GoTo` - it creates a mess out of your code. Use simple logic structures instead.

Comment: yes thanks for info, but the point is this code just read year (2020), and not read code `<> Year(Sheet9.Cells(a, 51))` because input year was blank. thats why show type mismatch

Comment: i think the problem is not the CInt, the problem code not read 
`<> Year(Sheet9.Cells(a, 51))` because reflect value " " 
in input file, I dont fill the value, and how to add statement elseif if number <> blank value?
any advise sir/madam?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `CInt` method returns a Runtime error when passed a non numeric value.
You can use

```vb
IsNumeric(SheetName.Cells(2, 3))
```

method to perform a type check before using `CInt`. `IsNumeric` will return you `true` or `false` based on the type of input passed.

#### Update

In case of date type you can use `IsDate()` method to validate that the cell value is of date type or not. Only after type check use `Year()` method.

Comment: Also specify from which sheet this `Cells(2,3)` is, in other way it can take wrong values.

Comment: i think the problem is not the CInt, the problem code not read 
`<> Year(Sheet9.Cells(a, 51))` because reflect value " " 
any advise sir/madam?

Comment: In my opinion the problem code not read `<> Year(Sheet9.Cells(a, 51))` because reflect value ("") I don't fill any value on InputBox which mean ("") and my question, how to add statement elseif number <> blank value ("")?

Comment: `Cells(2,3)` output was "2020" 
and `<> Year(Sheet9.Cells(a, 51))` output was ""